# Using variable from one method in another method

Tags: class, oop, variables, methods, local

What I am trying to do is use the second method to create a pattern so that in the first method I only have to write the second method name with a parameter, in order to extract different values from a response body by passing the key-name as parameter.

The response from the second method displays an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'response'"

```
public class BDDStyledMethod {


    public static void GetActivityById(){

        Response response=Authentication.Creds("www.randomurl.com");
       
        System.out.println("The extracted thing is: " + bodyResponse("name"));

    }
    public static String bodyResponse(String exe){

       
        JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
        String bodyExample = jsonPathEvaluator.get(exe).toString();
        return bodyExample;
    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Aside: This is a java specific question, not an object-oriented question.*

The crux of your question is about java scopes. The variable `response` is defined in the `GetActivityById` method. That method has a `{` and a `}`. That is the scope of the variable. What *scope of a variable* means, is that the variable is only visible - meaning, it only "exists" **[1]** after it was defined, **[2]** until the end of the scope (the curly brackets) it was defined in.

However, if you call a method, *methodB* from *methodA*, then *methodB* will have its own scope, which is separate from the scope of *methodA* which is the method calling it.

The method `bodyResponse` only has access to variables defined in its scope or passed into it as a parameter. So, to share a variable from one method to another, one way to do that is to pass it as a variable. You did this already with the `exe` variable. So, do the same for the `response` variable to fix this error:

```
public static void GetActivityById(){

        Response response=Authentication.Creds("www.randomurl.com");
       
        System.out.println("The extracted thing is: " + bodyResponse("name", response));//note I added *response*

    }
    public static String bodyResponse(String exe, Response response){//note I added *response*

       
        JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
        String bodyExample = jsonPathEvaluator.get(exe).toString();
        return bodyExample;
    }
```